# trying to compare lines of code in a text file

Tags: java

I am currently trying to compare the lines in a textfile to find the shortest line and longest line and display how many characters are in each. The code I have listed below allows me to count all the character, words, and lines. I have no idea where to start comparing the lines? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Test{

public static void main(String [] args){

System.out.println("Please enter the filename: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String fileName = input.nextLine();

 FileReader fReader;
    try {
        fReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
        String cursor; // 
        String content = "";
        int lines = 0;
        int words = 0;
        int chars = 0;


        while((cursor = reader.readLine()) != null){
            // count lines
            lines += 1;
            content += cursor;

            // count words
            String []_words = cursor.split(" ");
            for( String w : _words)
            {
              words++;        
            }

        }
        chars = content.length();

        System.out.println("The filename is " + fileName);
        System.out.println(chars + " Characters,");
        System.out.println(words + " words and " + lines + " lines.");


    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       // Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         System.out.println("An error has occured: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create 2 vars to store short and long lines...

```
String longest = "";
String shortest = "";
```

Then in your existing code, compare with current line:

```
while((cursor = reader.readLine()) != null){
    // compare shortest and longest.
    int currentSize = cursor.lenght;

    if (currentSize > longest.lenght || longest.equals("")) {
        longest = cursor;
    } else if (currentSize < shortest.lenght || longest.equals("")) {
        shortest = cursor;
    }

    // count lines
    lines += 1;
    content += cursor;

    // count words
    String []_words = cursor.split(" ");
    for( String w : _words)
    {
        words++;        
    }

}
```

After the loop you can do what you need with results:

```
 System.out.println("Longest line has " + longest.lenght);
 System.out.println("Shortest line has " + shortest.lenght);
```

If you only need the sizes and not the lines you can create `int` variables.

```
int longest = 0;
int shortest = 0;

// then inside the loop
int currentSize = cursor.lenght;

if (currentSize > longest || currentSize = 0) {
    longest = currentSize;
} else if (currentSize < shortest || currentSize = 0) {
    shortest = currentSize;
}
```

Comment: great to help. I see you're new at StackOverflow. If the answer helped, you can vote up (or down) with arrows in the side the answers and accept it with the check symbol. Check this link for further info http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I tried to upvote but it says i need a reputation of 15 :( I will look further into it. Thank you.

Comment: it's true, you cannot upvote for the moment, but for each accepted answer you will get +2 points ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 String variables, one to hold the shortest String and one to hold the longest String.  Then as you process each line, compare the length of the current line to the shortest/longest.

If it is shorter than your shortest String, set the shortest String to the current line.

else

If it is longer than your longest String, set the longest String to the current line.

Process the results at the end on those two String variables.